# SSMS 2012 concat of two variables doesn't take a value of other variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, sql-server-2012, declaration

I have some problem with concat two variables into one, maybe someone of you will tell me what I'm doing wrong or it is even possible to do what I want to do.
I have some declared variables - VAR1, VAR2, etc. All of them are declared. What I want to do is concat two variables (second part of variable is dynamically generated, it's current number of iteration) to one and using this one in code.

Example part of my code:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1, @MaxVar INT = 10;


DECLARE @VAR1 varchar(15) = '12345'
DECLARE @VAR2 varchar(15) = '67890'
DECLARE @VAR3 varchar(15) = '246810'
....


WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @MaxVar)
BEGIN

DECLARE @a varchar(4)= '@VAR'
DECLARE @b varchar(2)=  cast (@LoopCounter as varchar(2))
DECLARE @c varchar(6)= @a + @b

SELECT 
(SELECT fullname FROM company WHERE company_id = @c) as Vendor,
,@c as company_id
...

SET @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1 
END;
```

Unfortunately, all I receive is:

```
Vendor  company_id
-----   ----------
null    @VAR1
null    @VAR2
null    @VAR3
...     ...
```

I've tried lots of combinations, for ex.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT fullname FROM company WHERE company_id = '@VAR + cast (@LoopCounter as varchar(2))') as Vendor,
,'@VAR + cast (@LoopCounter as varchar(2))' as company_id
...
```

or

```
SELECT 
(SELECT fullname FROM company WHERE company_id = @VAR + ' + @b + ') as Vendor,
,@VAR + ' + @b + ' as company_id
...
```

But all I have is null or bad declaration od @VAR's.

Why concat of @a + @b, which in first iteration is '@VAR1', does not take a value assigned to @VAR1 -> '12345'? Why it's string, not a value of variable? What should I change or declate to make this right?

Please help :)

Comment: because you're asking it to match a string literal. In your example, the query in the first loop would look like `SELECT fullname FROM company WHERE company_id = '@VAR1'`. So unless you have any companies where the ID is _literally_ '@VAR1' it will fail. You can't do this kind of dynamic variable assignment in SQL, unless you do entirely dynamic SQL (i.e. build the whole query as a string and then use sp_executesql to execute the string) - but then you must be careful about SQL injection etc.

Comment: Thank you for reply, that is as I though, unfortunatelly... SQL injections does not come into play, script is running locally.

Comment: ok well if there's no risk from malicious user input you can probably go down the dynamic SQL route to build up your query each time. Maybe using a table variable would work as well, so you can loop through the possible variables more easily than having individual separate variable names.